# What has changed? $ variables not seen

Tags: php, forms

On my server, instead of using $_POST['username'] to collect data after a form has been submitted, I have simply been able to use $username

so, after a form submission:

```
echo $username;
```

would produce the same as:

```
echo $_POST['username']
```

I have just moved to a new server and this seems to not work on my new server... is this something that was set in PHP maybe?

I now have the task of going through an entire site otherwise and changing a very form driven site to use the new $_POST[] method (well not new but you know what I mean)

Also, is NOT using $_POST[], as I have been in the past, bad practice and why?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic creation of variables from $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE is the effect of the [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) INI directive.

It is deprecated due to security issues and is turned off by default on recent installations. I suggest you never rely on this feature and always explicitly specify the original source of your data.

Comment: Well, not so recent...I've never seen it ON apart from servers running php 4.X, but I know it's not something tied to a particular PHP version (5.3 deprecates it, thankfully).

Comment: I just read up on this and tried to break into my own site, thanks guys, I managed it in one URL line!! The server people I am with had globals turned on, rewrite it is then! Aaaargh but for all the right reasons...